# R - Cleaning dataset columns for NA,NaN,DIV/0

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataset with 160 columns. Some of these columns contains a lot of NA and #DIV/0!
I load the data in the following way:

`training = read.csv("training.csv",header = TRUE,na.strings = c("NA","NaN","","#DIV/0!"))`

How can I keep only columns that contains values in all rows?

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SRivero's answer works, here is another

```
set.seed(1234)
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(100000),1000,10))
dat[sample(1:100,20,replace=TRUE),sample(1:10,3,replace=TRUE)] <- NA

# apply through each column seeing if any are NAs
dat[,sapply(dat,function(x) !any(is.na(x)))]

# Check if both answers give same result
all.equal(dat[,which(sapply(dat,function(x) !any(is.na(x))))],
dat[ , colSums(is.na(dat)) == 0])
[1] TRUE
```

Though mine is a bit faster

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(dat[,sapply(dat,function(x) !any(is.na(x)))],
dat[ , colSums(is.na(dat)) == 0])
Unit: microseconds
                                           expr     min       lq      mean   median      uq      max neval
 dat[, sapply(dat, function(x) !any(is.na(x)))]  87.464  89.7790  94.51491  90.9830  97.124  190.865   100
                dat[, colSums(is.na(dat)) == 0] 197.958 199.9585 226.49657 201.4265 207.278 1382.612   100
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
training[ , colSums(is.na(training)) == 0]
```

Comment: This should do what you want. If show the dataset maybe is easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `select_if()` from `dplyr`. It lets you use a predicate on the columns of a data frame. Only those columns for which the predicate returns `TRUE` will be selected:

```
library(dplyr)
select_if(dat, function(x) !any(is.na(x))
```